How can I inline edit Users on a custom list view?
I am trying to use the Enhanced User List View to edit multiple users.  I have the setting enabled, and can edit User records inline on the default "Recently Viewed" list.  However, when I try to use the "All Users" list that was a created by Salesforce, or edit from a custom list view, the pencil icon doesn't appear, and I am unable to edit records.  Is there any way to enable this?

Referring to the documentation from Salesforce here. They have stated a few points, but here's the one I would like to cite for this question (Specifically, text in bold):

If you want to edit fields inline, make sure they’re present in the user profile page layout. In the User Profile Layout, add the required fields, and refresh the list view.

Upon testing in my developer org, I saw that "Recently Viewed" list view, has the following fields

Fullname
Title
Phone
Email

All of the 4 fields are available in my User Profile Page Layout. Hence, inline editing is possible on "Recently Viewed" list view.
Now when switching to "All Users" list view. I see the following fields

Fullname
Alias
Username
Role
Active
Profile

Where item 2 to item 6, fields, were NOT in the User Profile Page Layout by default (at least in my developer org).
Therefore, "All Users" list view is NOT inline editable. To make inline editable possible, we have to add all of the fields, which in this case, (Alias, Username, Role, Active and Profile) into the User Profile Page Layout. Once, the fields are added to the page layout. Now, inline editing is possible on the "All Users" list view.
Therefore, to summarize, if you want a User list to be inline editable, you have to add the fields to the page layout.
Ending note: Please read the official documentation, as there are other points to consider.

This worked for me.  Thank you!
